# Select an select option without using the attribute select(do a fake mouseclick)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, forms

I've been searching for already a long time but I can't find anything so I have a question.

I have a form select option field and that form has 5 select fields. When you select something in the first field the second field will fill itself with option with what you've selected. I think that the update is getting done by Ajax. But I also want to use the form option field with buttons(div/a) that will select an option in the select fields but when you use

```
$('#finder-2--5').val("413058").attr('selected', 'selected').parent().focus();
```

the field is not clicked so the next field won't reload.

So is there a possible option to fake a real mouseclick in javascript/jQuery.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `But I also want to use the form option field with buttons(div/a) that will select an option in the select fields`... Are you saying you want to be able to click a `button` or `anchor` which then will select one of the options in the `<select>` element but so that the `click` event of that `select` element is also triggered?

Comment: bind `change` handler to `<select>`. Really not clear what you want...provide html sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to [dispatch a click event](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-EventTarget-dispatchEvent) from the option element. Since you're using jQuery, you can use the *trigger* method. Some browsers in use will not respond to clicks on option elements, though I think jQuery's event model provides a substitute.

Setting the selected attribute doesn't necessarily make an option selected, it just sets the selected attribute (which is a [boolean attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#attributes-95)) and affects the *defaultSelected* property. To make an option selected, either set the select's *selectedIndex* property to the index of the option, or set the option's *selected* property to `true` (i.e. boolean `true`, not the string "true") using the *prop* method.

#### Edit

It seems that the best option is to put a change listener on the select element.

Comment: In addition to add a solution to OPs issue of auto-filling the second select based on the selection of the first. OP should extrapolate the code which loads the values into the second select into a separate function which then can be called from either the `click/change` event of the first select or manually after selecting an option programmatically  using one of the suggested methods. That would possibly be cleaner than simulating a click event after the option has been selected.